# bentley ottman algorithm sweep line data structure implementation

Tags: algorithm, implementation

Can someone tell me what data structure is ideal to use for the Sweep line and Event queue in Bentley Ottman Algorithm? Heap makes sense for the event queue but not for the Sweep line as we need the two neighbours of the last inserted point.How to achieve log(n) insertion time and find neighbours in the sweep line data structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A balanced binary search tree is traditional.